# Videojs SET Video End point

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I can set the video player to play a video start at a specific point using

```
player.ready(function() {
    player.currentTime(20);
});
```

I would like to be able to set and end time as I please. Let's say after 30 seconds.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

All that comes to mind is

```
setTimeout(function(){player.tech_.src(null)}, 30000)
```

This will roughly remove the current stream src.